# R: change file name in the for loop

Tags: r, loops

This is a fake example:

```
i=1
for (i in 1:3){

m<- model()
result<- fit.model(data)

}
```

Instead of overwrite the result every time, how do I change the name in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

assign the result to i and go to next loop. your results will be saved as result_1, result_2 depending on i

```
assign(paste0("result_", i), result)
```

Comment: add the line after ```results <- fitmodel(data)